# Invalid argument in IE9.js (code 0) in Line: 6 Char: 28214

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I am using IE8 in compatibility view and while this does produce acceptable rendering, this only happens after a refresh.

When the page is first loaded, it wouldn't display at all (staying at the previous page) and only give this error:

```
Invalid argument
IE9.js
Code: 0
Line: 6
Char: 28214
```

My searches for a solution to this problem yielded the following [old thread](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=300) which *doesn't* provide any solution.

It does however provide a link to the *minimal* reproducible test case that demonstrates this bug.

http://panoptic.com/ie7-js-300/

Hit that URL with IE8 with "Compatibility View" turned on, and you'll see the JS error.

When examining the `IE9.js` file, line 6 char 28214 point to the `.` in:

```
g.runtimeStyle[a]=
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? (yes, it needs to work in compatibility view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you some direction to where the problem. http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=300#c12

Even I am searching for the solution.

Update : http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=354

Comment: Unfortunately, my project took me elsewhere and I didn't have a chance to verify the correctness of the solution. So accepting (+1), until/unless I happen to discover otherwise.